# UNIX average of specific employee as per designation

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, grep

This is an example of a text file to be given as input

```
  Name,Designation,Salary
  Hari,Engineer,35000
  Suresh,Consultant,80000
  Umesh,Engineer,45500
  Maya,Analyst,50000
  Guru,Consultant,100000
  Sushma,Engineer,30000
  Mohan,Engineer,30000
```

My code should be able to run find the average salary of particular employee's designation. For example,

```
bash script.sh employees.txt Analyst
```

Then my output should be

```
50000
```

My current code to find just the average of all employees doesn't work. I am new to shell. This is my current code

```
count="$(tail -n 1 salary.txt | grep -o '^[^\s]\+')"

echo "$count"
salary="$(grep -o '[^ ]\+$' salary.txt | paste -sd+)"

echo "$salary"

echo "($salary)/$count" | bc
```

I get empty values as results.

Comment: You _can_ do this in bash, but maybe you should consider using a more versatile language like awk, Python or Ruby instead.

Comment: There's something wrong with almost every one of those lines. Take them apart, one by one, and run each subcommand in the shell to see what it does. Then modify until it does the right thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is better done in `awk`:

```
awk -F, -v dgn='Engineer' '$2 == dgn{s += $3; ++c} END{printf "%.2f\n", s/c}' file.csv
```

```
35125.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(since OP requested for script way, so adding it in a script way where passing 1st argument as Input_file name and 2nd argument as string whose avg is needed).

```
cat script.ksh
file="$1"
name="$2"

awk -F, -v field="$name" '{a[$2]+=$3;b[$2]++} END{for(i in a){if(i == field){print a[i]/b[i]}}}'  "$file"
```

Now run the script as follwos.

```
./script.ksh Input_file Analyst
50000
```

Comment: @John Doe, Good that you have selected any answer as correct one. Would like to ask you here the reason for de-selcting mine answer, since I have writen code as per your ask(though anubhava sir's code is great no issues with it), please do mention here.

Answer (score 0):

[GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) is a useful tool for calculating this kind of thing:

```
$ datamash -sHt, groupby 2 mean 3 < employees.txt
```

Combine with `grep` to limit it to just the title you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in the shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
designation=$2

# code to validate user input here ...

sum=0
count=0
while IFS=, read -r n d s; do 
    if [[ ${designation,,} == "${d,,}" ]]; then 
        (( sum += s ))
        (( count++ ))
    fi
done < "$file"

if (( count == 0 )); then 
    echo "No $designation found in $file"
else
    echo $((sum / count))
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
 perl -F, -lane ' if(/Engineer/) { $dsg+=$F[2];$c++ } END { print $dsg/$c } ' file
```

with your given inputs

```
$ cat john.txt
  Name,Designation,Salary
  Hari,Engineer,35000
  Suresh,Consultant,80000
  Umesh,Engineer,45500
  Maya,Analyst,50000
  Guru,Consultant,100000
  Sushma,Engineer,30000
  Mohan,Engineer,30000

$ perl -F, -lane ' if(/Engineer/) { $dsg+=$F[2];$c++ } END { print $dsg/$c } ' john.txt
35125

$
```